# Handle browser's Back and Next buttons after logout Python

Tags: javascript, python, http-headers, browser-cache, tipfy

After log out from my app, I have redirected the user to the log in page. At the log in page, when someone click back or next buttons of the browser, I want to redirect him to the login page  as same as gmail or facebook.

So I tried to clear cache as follow,

```
class LogoutHandler(SecurePageHandler):
def get(self):
    self.session_store.delete_cookie('session')
    self.session.clear()

    response = self.redirect('/')
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'
    return response
```

But still the back button directing me to the previous page which I logged out from.

I noted that, *Referer* field in the *Request Headers* still keeping the previous URL. So I think, I should have to override it. But I couldn't find a way to modify my Request object.

I am trying on this more than half a day and I sincerely appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use javascript's [`window.location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) after logout so that the page you don't want to go back to is replace with the new login page.

Comment: Thanx jcollado. I could see it's not working on IE. I tested following tutorial. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_replace